# Numpad number layout

Tags: python

Think of the numpad number layout.

`hvd = horizontal, vertical or diagonal`

`coord = 1,2 or 3` if horizontal or vertical and 1 or 2 if diagonal (1 is up, 2 is down)...

`hello('v', 2)` - Asking for the second vertical column etc

```
def hello(hvd, coord):
    if hvd == 'h':
        print "horizontal it is"
        if coord == 1:
            print "789"
        elif coord == 2:
            print "456"
        elif coord == 3:
            print "789"
        else:
            print "coord is wrong"
    elif hvd == 'v':
        print "vertical it is"
        if coord == 1:
            print "741"
        elif coord == 2:
            print "852"
        elif coord == 3:
            print "963"
        else:
            print "coord is wrong"
    elif hvd == 'd':
        print "diagonal it is"
        if coord == 1:
            print "159"
        elif coord == 2:
            print "753"
        else:
            print "coord is wrong"
    else:
        print "hvd is wrong"
```

I just want a critique on this function. I am interested in knowing if there is a nicer way to do what I am doing and if there is anything wrong with my code.

It seems quite hard to look at especially since it contains place holder statements and the actual statements I want might be 10 lines long each... Would be unwieldy surely?

Answer (score 7):

A nicer way to do the same would be to use a dictionary:

```
def hello(hvd, coord):        
    d = {'h': ["789", "456", "123"],
         'v': ["741", "852", "963"],   
         'd': ["159", "753"]}
    try:
        print d[hvd][coord-1]
    except IndexError:
        print "coord is wrong"
    except KeyError:
        print "hvd is wrong"
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to print from inside the function? Isn't returning a value more reusable?

Comment: @Caridorc Yes, that would be a further improvement. alexwlchan has that angle covered now.

Answer (score 4):

A few suggestions:

- **A function should either do some work, or return a value – not both.** Your function is (1) deciding which set of digits to return, and (2) printing them to stdout. It should just return the set of digits, and let the caller decide how to use them.
- **Don’t use print statements for errors.** Raise exceptions instead – that allows callers to handle problems gracefully with `try … except`, rather than having to parse what just got sent to stdout.

  As a corollary, it would be good for your error messages to include the invalid value. This can be useful for debugging – if your function is several layers deep and throws an exception, it may not be obvious to the end user what the bad value was.

  You may also want to specify valid values.
- **Use a dictionary for the values, not multiple if branches.** This is a more concise and readable way to express the information.
- **You can be more defensive to user input.** If the user enters 'H', 'V' or 'D', their intention is unambiguous – but your code will reject it. Perhaps lowercase their input first?
- **I have no idea why the function is called hello().** It doesn’t tell me anything about what the function does. There’s not a docstring either. A better name and documentation would tell me:

  - What the function is supposed to do
  - What arguments I’m supposed to supply

  You’ve already written most of this in the question – just put it in the code!

Here’s a partially revised version:

```
def numpad_digits(hvd, coord):
    digits = {
        "h": ["123", "456", "789"],
        "v": ["741", "852", "963"],   
        "d": ["159", "753"]
    }
    try:
        # Offset by one - the user will be thinking of a 1-indexed list
        return digits[hvd.lower()][coord-1]
    except IndexError:
        raise ValueError("Invalid value for coord: %s" % coord)
    except KeyError:
        raise ValueError("Invalid value for hvd: %s" % hvd)
```

Answer (score 1):

The danger of having the programmer do the computer's work is that you might do it wrong. In this case, it's impossible to get the "123" row due to a copy-and-paste bug.